# Emgucv turn the black background transparent

Tags: c#, background, emgucv, transparent

I'm very new to Emgucv, so need a little help?

The code below is mainly taken from various places from Google. It will take a jpg file (which has a green background) and allow, from a separate form to change the values of `h1` and `h2` settings so as to create (reveal) a mask. 
Now what I want to be able to do with this mask is to turn it transparent.

At the moment it will just display a black background around a person (for example), and then saves to file.

I need to know how to turn the black background transparent, if this is the correct way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

What I have so far is in C# :

```
imgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(FileName);

Image<Hsv, Byte> hsvimg = imgInput.Convert<Hsv, Byte>();

//extract the hue and value channels
Image<Gray, Byte>[] channels = hsvimg.Split();      // split into components
Image<Gray, Byte> imghue = channels[0];             // hsv, so channels[0] is hue.
Image<Gray, Byte> imgval = channels[2];             // hsv, so channels[2] is value.

//filter out all but "the color you want"...seems to be 0 to 128 (64, 72) ?
Image<Gray, Byte> huefilter = imghue.InRange(new Gray(h1), new Gray(h2));

// TURN IT TRANSPARENT somewhere around here?

pictureBox2.Image = imgInput.Copy(mask).Bitmap;

imgInput.Copy(mask).Save("changedImage.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I really understand what you are trying to do. But a mask is a binary object. A mask is usually black for what you do not want and white for what you do. As far as I know, there is no transparent mask, as to me that makes no sense. Masks are used to extract parts of an image by masking out the rest.

Maybe you could elaborate on what it is you want to do?

Doug

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have the solution I was looking for. I found some code on stackoverflow which I've tweaked a little :

```
public Image<Bgra, Byte> MakeTransparent(Image<Bgr, Byte> image, double r1, double r2)
{
    Mat imageMat = image.Mat;                      

    Mat finalMat = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
    Mat tmp      = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
    Mat alpha    = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);

    CvInvoke.CvtColor(imageMat, tmp, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

    CvInvoke.Threshold(tmp, alpha, (int)r1, (int)r2, ThresholdType.Binary);

    VectorOfMat rgb = new VectorOfMat(3);

    CvInvoke.Split(imageMat, rgb);

    Mat[] rgba = { rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], alpha };

    VectorOfMat vector = new VectorOfMat(rgba);

    CvInvoke.Merge(vector, finalMat);

    return finalMat.ToImage<Bgra, Byte>();
}
```

I'm now looking at adding SmoothGaussian to the mask to create a kind on blend, where the two images are layered, rather than a sharp cut-out.